# (PHP) str_replace not working while inserting to database

Tags: php, string, str-replace

i have a problem. I am not good at php, so i am asking for help. I made table in database with couple of rows:

[image]

Also i have simple (probably not safe) (insert data) script:

**Connection:**

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');
```

**POST DATA**

```
$renginioid = ($_POST['renginioid']);
$renginioid = strtolower($_POST['renginioid']);
$renginioid = str_replace(" ", "-", $renginioid);
$renginioid = str_replace("ą", "a", $renginioid);
$renginioid = str_replace("č", "c", $renginioid);
$renginioid = str_replace("ę", "e", $renginioid);
/* etc */
```

**INSERT**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO renginiai(renginioid, pavadinimas, vadovai, programa, menesis, adresas, mda6) VALUES('$renginioid', '$pavadinimas', '$vadovai', '$programa', '$menesis', '$adresas', '$mda6')");
$stmt->execute();
```

**PROBLEM:**

I am using same POST at $renginioid and $pavadinimas. strtolower works perfectly, while str_replace does not work at all.

I need to replace ą to a, č to c ...etc, but this script does not work. (i need to transform this letters to english letters).

**OTHER PROBLEM:**

this script can insert english letters to all of rows, but if i am using other letters, than all rows doing job perfecly except renginioid row. That row is pain for me a couple of hours..

renginioid row is a primary row.

Thanks to all of you to any of help.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: i tryed that couple of mins ago, but database gives me "?-?-?".

Comment: Btw, this is not how you should be using prepared statements; the `->execute()` is used to send the variables and `->prepare()` should only have place holders.

Answer (score 0):

In `HTML` to show utf8 speacial characters, put this in your `<head>`

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In PHP to show utf8 from table rows, store in a `$variable` an show in this way:

```
utf8_encode($variable);
```

To push the rows in tables, use this:

```
utf8_decode($variable);
```

More info, here:

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php
http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-decode.php

***OR***

Use this special html characters table to improve your str_replace code: http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cz.htm

Comment: what do you mean: "To push the rows in tables, use this" ? After your tutorial, now i am getting this: "äääää¯å¡å³å«å¾".

Comment: To insert in database, try replace with this list http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cz.htm like $renginioid = str_replace("ą", "&#261;", $renginioid); without utf8_encode & utf8_decode functions

Comment: See this: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10381079-Encode-Lithuanian-language

Comment: everyting is ok with my language in database and script. Script inserts letters perfectly to all rows, except renginioid row. I dont need those letters in that row, what i need is english letters in that row. I am writing in input LT letters, than replacing space with dash, and than i need to transform LT letters to EN letters :/ i am grateful for you help, but it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

For that use htmlspecialchars :)

```
   $renginioid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['renginioid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```